# chrome.runtime.onMessage response with async await

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, async-await

I want to use async await in an onMessage listener:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(async (request, sender, sendResponse) =>{
    var key = await getKey();
    sendResponse(key);
});
```

However I get undefined when I send a message.

From the [documentation for chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/messaging/#simple):

> If you want to asynchronously use sendResponse(), add return true; to the onMessage event handler.

This works when I use a callback.

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(async (request, sender, sendResponse) =>{
    getKey(key => {
        sendResponse(key);
    });
    return true;
});
```

However I would like to leverage the await syntax. But it does not seem to work and still returns undefined:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(async (request, sender, sendResponse) =>{
    var key = await getKey();
    sendResponse(key);
    return true;
});
```

Answer (score 127):

#### tl;dr

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
  (async () => {
    // async code goes here
    // ...
    const result = await getSomething();
    sendResponse(result);
  })();

  // Important! Return true to indicate you want to send a response asynchronously
  return true;
});
```

#### Or extract to an async function.

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
  doSomethingWith(request).then(sendResponse);
  return true; // return true to indicate you want to send a response asynchronously
});

async function doSomethingWith(request) {
  var key = await getKey();
  // await .....
  return key;
}
```

The return value of an `async` function is implicitly wrapped in `Promise.resolve`. See [async doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

The `return true;` statement did the trick. It tells Chrome that you want to send a response asynchronously.

See [onMessage](https://web.archive.org/web/20190330142950/https://developer.chrome.com/apps/runtime#event-onMessage) (web archived, as the new document doesn't mention this hidden return).

#### Or extract to a utility

If you feel that you will use it most frequently, create a utility, something like:

```js
const wrapAsyncFunction = (listener) => (request, sender, sendResponse) => {
  // the listener(...) might return a non-promise result (not an async function), so we wrap it with Promise.resolve()
  Promise.resolve(listener(request, sender)).then(sendResponse);
  return true; // return true to indicate you want to send a response asynchronously
};

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  wrapAsyncFunction(async (request, sender) => {
    console.log(request, sender);

    const key = await getKey();
    // await .....
    return key;
  })
);
```

#### Or more generic

Use [mozilla/webextension-polyfill](https://github.com/mozilla/webextension-polyfill#basic-setup-with-module-bundlers)
if you prefer to "cross browsers" extension.

Example:

```js
var browser = require("webextension-polyfill");

browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener(async (msg, sender) => {
  console.log("BG page received message", msg, "from", sender);
  console.log("Stored data", await browser.storage.local.get());
});

browser.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(() => {
  browser.tabs.executeScript({file: "content.js"});
});
```

Comment: Thanks! works great after I removed the async from the listener and following your instructions

Comment: I don't understand how, but it works. How are parameters passed to sendResponse call?

Comment: @AlexSham it's a shorthand for: `doSomethingWith(request).then(result => sendResponse(result));`.

Comment: As mentioned in the code comment, `return true;` statement is important as it tells Chrome that you will send response asynchronously.

Comment: tl;dr; option seems quite familiar :)

Comment: Why `return true` is not mentioned anywhere in the document here: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/runtime/#method-sendMessage. Such important thing.

Comment: @Arst The new document (MV3) doesn't mention the `return true`, whereas the old one did. https://web.archive.org/web/20190330142950/https://developer.chrome.com/apps/runtime#event-onMessage

Comment: Works like a charm :) can't believe the new docs don't mention it... Anyway, worth mentioning: in case your background only wants to do sendResponse() for particular types of messages and not for others, `return true` should be done only when receiving those messages - otherwise the communication channel will be left open and an error will be thrown as soon as service worker becomes inactive.

Comment: Upvoting from 2024.

Comment: Mentioned in docs here: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/develop/concepts/messaging#simple

Comment: Issue tracker for docs omission: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/314359857

Answer (score 12):

The closest I could get:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
    (async () => {
        var key = await getKey();
        sendResponse(key);
    })();
    return true;
});
```

Comment: Beautiful! Sd be the accepted answer.

Comment: Works great. I like this best too.

Comment: d BEST solution

Comment: @daghan why did you revert my edit? I just formatted the code to look like JS (2 spaces) and added a title so more people would see the answer.

Comment: @mikemaccana your second edit completely altered the answer to a wrong and useless one, so I reverted all edits. Please leave it as it is.

Comment: @daghan It was literally the your code, just with `sleep()` instead of `getKey()` as an example async function, and formatted. But OK.

Answer (score 5):

> Function to call (at most once) when you have a response. The argument should be any JSON-ifiable object. If you have more than one onMessage listener in the same document, then only one may send a response. This function becomes invalid when the event listener returns, unless you **return true** from the event listener to indicate you wish to send a response asynchronously (this will keep the message channel open to the other end until sendResponse is called).

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/runtime/#event-onMessage

have to say the official doc is really hard to read.

Comment: Sadly it's even worse now - that text has been removed. That link now just says "returns
boolean | undefined" with no further explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if Chrome extension runtime environment supports the async/await syntax, but you can use a transpiler (i.e. Babel) to have it converted to for example ES5. Then you can define a wrapper function like this:

```
function asChromeListener(listener) {
  return (message, sender, sendResponse) => {
    const returnValue = listener(message, sender);

    if (isPromise(returnValue)) {
      returnValue.then(sendResponse);
      return true;
    }
    else {
      if (typeof returnValue !== 'undefined') {
        sendResponse(returnValue);
      }
      return false;
    }
  };
}

function isPromise(value) {
  return typeof value === 'object' && value !== null && 'then' in value && 'catch' in value;
}
```

Which you can then use like:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(asChromeListener(async (message, sender) => {
  return await doMyAsyncWork(message);
});
```

Since we use **TypeScript**, here's also the snippet that we actually use (with generic types).

```js
export function asChromeListener<M, S, R extends Function>(listener: (message: M, sender: S) => any) {
  return (message: M, sender: S, sendResponse: R) => {
    const returnValue = listener(message, sender);

    if (isPromise(returnValue)) {
      returnValue.then(sendResponse);
      return true;
    }
    else {
      if (typeof returnValue !== 'undefined') {
        sendResponse(returnValue);
      }
      return false;
    }
  };
}

function isPromise(value: any) {
  return typeof value === 'object' && value !== null && 'then' in value && 'catch' in value;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I was unable to use `async/await`, however I did manage to make it work using `then`. You need to return `true` at the very end of your `onMessage` function.

Here is an example of how I'm asynchronously retrieving the current active tab to my `content` script.

background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (data, sender, sendResponse) {

  if (data.type === 'getTab') {
    const promise = new Promise(async (resolve) => {
      /* gets active tab info */
      let queryOptions = { active: true, currentWindow: true };
      let [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query(queryOptions);

      resolve(tab);
    });

    promise.then((tab) => {
      sendResponse(tab);
    });
  }


  return true;
});
```

content.js

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(
  {
    type: 'getTab'
  },
  function (data) {

    if (data.type === 'getTab') {
      console.log('my tab', data);
    }
  }
);
```

I hope this helps someone out there.
I've spent more time than I'd care to admit on this one.

Comment: I need some assistance on my chrome extension project to improve the code to avoid uncaught errors. Are you open for paid help?

Comment: I like this answer the best - I did use the IIFE async/away approach in the other answer I started to get some cases where the `onMessage()` simply wasn't being run. Also note **proper Promise support is onMessage() is in the standard, and implemented on Firefox, just not in Chrome yet** - see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/Runtime/onMessage. I'll stick with this approach until Chrome gets real Promise support in  onMessage()

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, it looks like Google Chrome Extensions don't support the `await` keyword. I've successfully used asynchronous `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener`'s before, and every time I try to use `await` I see this syntax error in the Chrome Debugging Tools, on the line that I use `await`:

[image: await not supported]

Here's how I've been testing:

I created a very basic listener:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(data, MessageSender, sendResponse) {
    sendResponse(awaitTester);
    var async = true;

    // returns true if asyncronous is needed
    if (async) return true;
});
```

my `awaitTester` function looks like this:

```
function awaitTester() {
    var prom = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            resolve('test');
        }, 4000);
    });

    var awaited = await prom;
    return awaited;
}
```

finally, my message sender is what you'd expect:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({}, function(message) {
    debugger;
    console.log(message);
});
```

And in the debugger / console I **always** get `undefined`.

Comment: You don't have a native support for async/await - you need to use some sort of tranapiller for that functionality.

Answer (score 0):

you could try this

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
  new Promise(async send => {
     

    var key = await getKey();
    send(key);


  }).then(sendResponse)
  return true;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way that worked for me.

popup.js

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener( async (request, sender, sendResponse) => {
    let response = '';
    switch (request.msg){
        case 'login' :
            response = await login();
            sendResponse({ msg: 'login_response', response: response });
            break;
        default:
            sendResponse(response);
    }
});
```

background.js

```js
       // Send a message to the background script
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({msg: 'login'});

        // Wait for a response from the background script
        const response = await new Promise(resolve => {
          chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function listener(message) {
            if (message.msg === 'login_response') {
              resolve(message.response);
            }
          });
        });

        console.log('Response received', response);
```