# Response is undefinded with async, await, promise

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, promise, async-await

In my `eventPage.js`(background, persistent=false):

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(async function(request, sender, sendResponse) {

    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
        chrome.downloads.search({id: files[i]}, function (item) { 
            sendfiles.push(item[0].id);
            resolve();
        });
    });

    console.log(sendfiles); // contains (item[0].id), means it did wait.

    sendResponse("hello"); // Should send hello back

    return true;
});
```

And in my `popup.js`:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage("",(response) => {
    alert(response); // alerts undefinded instead of hello
});
```

My error: 
`Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.`

As written in the comments of the code, It should respond to the request from the `popup.js` with `"hello"`, but because it waited in the `Promise`, I get the error and the `response` becomes `undefinded` before I can `sendResponse` my `"hello"` (I'm guessing this is what happening)..

Comment: We cannot flag this question as a duplicate since the following one has no accepted answer, but it looks close to your problem? [chrome.runtime.onMessage response with async await](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46628145/1913729)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This function becomes invalid when the event listener returns, unless you return true from the event listener to indicate you wish to send a response asynchronously (this will keep the message channel open to the other end until sendResponse is called).

From [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onMessage)

But using async-await, your function will return a Promise.

So you want to do this:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {

    chrome.downloads.search({id: files[i]}, 
      function (item) { 
        sendResponse(item[0].id);
      }
    );

   return true;
});
```

But really, you want to do this:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  (req, sender, sendResponse) => {
    chrome.downloads.search({id: files[i]}, 
       item => sendResponse(item[0].id);
    );
   return true;
});
```

Or at least, I do! :-)

For the looping. You want to return an array of files. So what you do in your program is:

1. Create an array of "A Promise of a file or undefined"
2. Wait for all those Promises to resolve.
3. Filter out the undefined.
4. Return the array of files.

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  (req, sender, sendResponse) => {
   if (req !== "files") { return } // why wait?

   Promise.all(files.map(file => 
     new Promise(resolve =>     
       chrome.downloads.search({id: file},
         item => resolve(item[0].exists ? 
         {
            filename: [item[0].filename, 
            id: item[0].id]
          } : undefined)))))
    .then(res => res.filter(i => !!i)) //remove empty
    .then(sendResponse)

  return true;
});
```

Basically, if you are using loops or variables, you're doing it wrong. Constants and functions only.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Looks about right.

Comment: Thanks for the correction! Though in my code I have the `chrome.downloads.search` inside a for loop. in every loop, inside the downloads.search, it will add an item to an array that will later be sent as a response. How do I do it? Also, some strange things are happening because it's doing the `chrome.downloads.search` parallel. The code: https://pastebin.com/0zmV76fi

Comment: Updated it for you.