# Chrome extension asynchronous chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener issue

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to check if there is a certain cookie on a website with the help of a background file. I will take different actions if there is a cookie and if there is not. However, my code in the background file does not return the data asynchronously. although the answer returns immediately, the actual answer returns after a few seconds. It returns the result directly without waiting. Although I use return true, it does not work asynchronously.
[image]

Background.js

`

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(async function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.contentScriptQuery == 0) {
        getCookies("https://www.trendyol.com/", "COOKIE_TY.Entrance")
            .then(m1 =>{console.log('aaa '+m1.status);sendResponse({status:m1.status})})
            .catch()
        return true;
    }
});


function getCookies(domain, name) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            chrome.cookies.get({ "url": domain, "name": name }, function (cookie) {
                var r1 = String(String(String(cookie.value).split('&tx=')[1]).split('&')[0])
                resolve({
                    status: true,
                    data: r1
                });
            });
        } catch (err) {
            resolve({
                status: false,
                data: false
            });
        }

    })
}
```

`

popup.js
`

```
class bot {
    constructor() {
        this.moderator()
    }

    message(status2, data) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            chrome.runtime.sendMessage(
                {
                    contentScriptQuery: status2,
                    data: data
                }, function (response) {
                    console.log('-----------------------');
                    console.log('-----------------------');
                    console.log(response);
                    console.log('---------------');
                    console.log('---------------');
                    if (response != undefined && response != "") {
                        resolve(response);
                    }
                    else {
                        reject()
                    }
                 
                });
        })
    }



    async moderator() {
        var dun = await this.message(0, false)
        console.log('dun');
        console.log(dun);
    }



}
window.onload = () => {
    const user = new bot()
}
```

`

What I expected was that the function would run asynchronously and return the data after checking the cookie. What I encountered is that the function returns undefined directly without running asynchronously. After the cookie is checked, it is written to the console, but the data is returned until it is written. I could not run it asynchronously.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [chrome.runtime.onMessage response with async await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44056271/chrome-runtime-onmessage-response-with-async-await)

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't. I tried to use return true in asynchronous functions. My function works if there is a fetch request, but it doesn't work when I try with cookie. My code is like the example you threw. Thank you for your response.

Comment: The answers to that question mention using a normal function for the callback to `addListener` and call an `async` function inside of it. Also, why are you using an `async` function if you do not use `await` inside of it (you use `.then(...)`).

Comment: Before this code, I was waiting with await instead of waiting with then. Thinking if the problem was in that part, I used then instead of await, but the async remained there. This was the answer thank you very much. If you want, I will accept it as an answer. You have been very helpful.

Comment: No need. I think there are a couple of similar questions out there already. In any case, I'm glad I could help.