# Why is the code not waiting for the listener to complete?

Tags: javascript, typescript, async-await, promise, content-script

I am trying to wait for the listener to listen to all messages before moving on to `console.log("Done")` using `await` but it is not happening. What am I missing.

```
const f = async (leftPaneRowEle,index) => {
    leftPaneRowEle.scrollIntoView()
    leftPaneRowEle.children[0].click()
    console.log('downloadBtn clicked for', leftPaneRowEle)

    const listener = (msg: any) => {
      console.log('frontend msg:', msg)
    }
    const port = Browser.runtime.connect()
    port.onMessage.addListener(async (msg, sender) => {
      console.log("BG page received message", msg, "from", sender);
      listener(msg)
    });
    await port.postMessage({ question: "Can you " + allTFBs[leftpaneindexes[index]] + ":" + desc })
    return async () => {
      await port.onMessage.removeListener(listener)
      await port.disconnect()
    }
}

const en: HTMLElement = document.querySelectorAll('#extensionListTable tbody')[0] as HTMLElement
const leftPaneRowEle0 = en.children[leftpaneindexes[0]]
await f(leftPaneRowEle0,0)
console.log("Done")
```

PS: My approach is inspired by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46628145/865220)

Comment: `f()` doesn't wait for any of the asynchronous operations to finish.

Comment: @Barmar yes thats the goal. where should  insert the `await` in `f()` ?

Comment: You need to use explicit `new Promise()`, since `addListener` doesn't return a promise.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39679505/using-await-outside-of-an-async-function

Comment: What do you mean by "*all messages*"? How do you know when the messages end?

Comment: When do you call the function returned by `f`?

Comment: Since `listener` is not asynchronous, there's no point in making the `addListener` callback an `async` function

Answer (score 0):

```
const f = (leftPaneRowEle, index) => {
  return new Promise(async (resolve) => {
    leftPaneRowEle.scrollIntoView();
    leftPaneRowEle.children[0].click();
    console.log('downloadBtn clicked for', leftPaneRowEle);

    const listener = (msg) => {
      console.log('frontend msg:', msg);
    };
    const port = Browser.runtime.connect();
    
    port.onMessage.addListener((msg, sender) => {
      console.log("BG page received message", msg, "from", sender);
      listener(msg);
    });

    port.onDisconnect.addListener(() => {
      console.log("Port disconnected");
      resolve(); // Resolve the Promise when the port disconnects
    });

    await port.postMessage({ question: "Can you " + allTFBs[leftpaneindexes[index]] + ":" + desc });
  });
};

const en = document.querySelectorAll('#extensionListTable tbody')[0] as HTMLElement;
const leftPaneRowEle0 = en.children[leftpaneindexes[0]];

(async () => {
  await f(leftPaneRowEle0, 0);
  console.log("Done");
})();
```

Try this

Comment: *"Try this"* - Why?  What was the problem in the original code?  What did you change?  How does that correct the problem?  Please edit the answer to elaborate.

Comment: This wraps the guts of f into a promise and adds a bunch of (irrelevant) terminators, but it doesn't provide an **answer** even if it fixes the issue. Should it do so, what's actually happening is that f is replaced by a promise that can be awaited, and that promise is resolved only when the onDisconnect event is triggered.

Comment: As a little example of mixing await, promises, and events, we actually just have sleeping inside an async function - `await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 5000))`

Comment: this apparently fixes the syntax, but my goal was to either use `async/await` or `promises` but not both. So not marking it as accepted for now.

Comment: Note that postMessage is void so no need for `await` and `async`.

Comment: @ishandutta2007, you can't use await with something that doesn't return a Promise natively. This answer is showing the only possible solution.

Comment: [Never use an `async function` as a `new Promise` executor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43036229/1048572)!

Comment: eslint has a issue with it though `Promise executor functions should not be async` with this line `return new Promise(async (resolve) => {`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

The code is not waiting for the listener to complete because the  `port.onMessage.addListener`  function is asynchronous and does not block the execution of subsequent code. Therefore, the  `console.log("Done")`  statement is executed before the listener has a chance to process all the messages.

To ensure that the code waits for the listener to complete before moving on, you can wrap the listener in a Promise and use  `await`  to wait for the Promise to resolve. Here's an updated version of the code:

```
const f = async (leftPaneRowEle, index) => {
  leftPaneRowEle.scrollIntoView();
  leftPaneRowEle.children[0].click();
  console.log('downloadBtn clicked for', leftPaneRowEle);

  const listenerPromise = new Promise((resolve) => {
    const listener = (msg) => {
      console.log('frontend msg:', msg);
      resolve(); // Resolve the Promise when the listener is called
    };
    const port = Browser.runtime.connect();
    port.onMessage.addListener(listener);

    port.postMessage({ question: "Can you " + allTFBs[leftpaneindexes[index]] + ":" + desc });
  });

  await listenerPromise; // Wait for the Promise to resolve

  return async () => {
    port.onMessage.removeListener(listener);
    port.disconnect();
  };
};

const en: HTMLElement = document.querySelectorAll('#extensionListTable tbody')[0] as HTMLElement;
const leftPaneRowEle0 = en.children[leftpaneindexes[0]];

await f(leftPaneRowEle0, 0);
console.log("Done");
```

In this updated code, the listener is wrapped in a Promise, and the  `resolve()`  function is called inside the listener to mark the Promise as resolved. Then, using  `await` , the code waits for the Promise to resolve before moving on to  `console.log("Done")` .

Please note that this code assumes that the  `Browser.runtime.connect()`  and  `port.postMessage()`  functions work as expected. Make sure you have the necessary setup and configurations in place for those functions to function correctly.

Comment: This waits only for the first message, not for "*all messages*" as requested by the OP