# Proper way to communicate chrome.sidePanel.open() success from service worker

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, google-chrome-extension

Note:

The new preferred approach with manifest V3 is to use Promises or the async/await for asynchronous operations. Please **do not** link "already answered" posts that use synchronous response patterns.

I've been reading through the docs but still confused on how this works because it seems there are so many ways to do things in Chrome extensions. https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/messaging/#simple

I'm sending a message to open a custom side panel from the content script for example:

```
// Open side panel
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: 'openSidePanel' });
```

Then in my service worker I'm opening the side panel:

```
// Listen for and respond to events 
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(async (message, sender, sendResponse) => {

  if (message.action === 'openSidePanel') {
    if (sender.tab && sender.tab.id) {
      try {
        await chrome.sidePanel.open({ tabId: sender.tab.id });
        console.log('Side panel opened successfully');
        await chrome.tabs.sendMessage(sender.tab.id, {success: true});
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error opening side panel:', error);
        await chrome.tabs.sendMessage(sender.tab.id, { success: false, errorMessage: error.message });
      }
      return true; // Indicates an asynchronous response
    } else {
      console.log('No sender tab information available');
      sendResponse({ success: false });
      return false;
    }
  }

});
```

Now in my content I can check for success or error:

```
// Listener for incoming messages
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((response) => {  
  if (response.success) {
    console.log("Success: Side panel opened");
  } else if (response.errorMessage) {
      console.log("Error:", response.errorMessage);
  } else {
      console.log("Unrecognized message format:", response);
  }
});
```

The issue: I am getting the success message when side panel is opened but I'm not sure if this is the correct way to do it.

It seems like would be the correct way:

```
const response = chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: 'openSidePanel' });
```

but this gives me undefined and the horror error "Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received."

What is the recommended way to handle this with manifest v3 and ES6?

Comment: You can use the `sendResponse` function instead of `chrome.tabs.sendMessage(sender.tab.id, ....)`. To do that property, don't use an `async` function as a parameter for `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(..)`.

Comment: @Titus async is needed to use await, to wait for the message to send/action.

Comment: @Titus to my knowledge V3 can return promises.

Comment: Yes, V3 returns promises but this is a callback function and it has nothing to do with that. And yes, you can only use `await` in `async` functions, the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44056271/1552587) contains some solutions for that.

Comment: @Titus thanks but my question is regarding best practce for the v3 manifest. In Manifest V3, Chrome has moved away from the use of synchronous response patterns in favor of more asynchronous pattern. The preferred approach is to use Promises or the async/await. So marking my question "already answered" will point people to old ways of developing chrome extensions.

Comment: All this has to do with event listeners, those are not promises, what has changed to promises in V3 are things like storage (eg: instead of `chrome.storage.local.get('something', function callback() {..})`, you can use `const values = await chrome.storage.local.get('something')`) but, things like `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(..)` are not `Promise` based. The important part is `addListener`, all those do not return promises.

Comment: @Titus the idea is that sendResponse is not recommended in V3 because it is synchronous. It does not fit with asynchronous patterns in V3. We should not recommended any answers using outdated  patterns. I specifically asked for a "recommended way to handle this with manifest v3 and ES6". Why do mods close the question and recommend answers that use synchronous patterns?

Comment: *sendResponse is not recommended in V3* What makes you say that? The [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/runtime/#event-onMessage) doesn't mention that. Like I've said before, when it comes to event listeners, those have not change to promises in V3. The questions that yours is marked as a duplicate of will fix your problem and those methods are the recommended way of doing that even in V3.

Comment: Also the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44056271/chrome-runtime-onmessage-response-with-async-await) that I've mentioned before have descriptions of what will happen when you use an `async function` as a callback.

Comment: @Titus there is a caution message here regarding sendResponse() https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/messaging/ they say it's "valid if used synchronously". V3 prefers synchronous patterns so one can conclude that obviously it's not recommended to use sendResponse on V3.  Furthermore, the suggested already answered posts are wrong. They use sendResponse and notice how many dev say in the comments that it does not work (because they're using the latest V3). Admit your mistake and unclose this question.

Comment: @Titus again the purpose of my question is to get the LATEST best practice. Anything suggesting to use sendResponse() in V3 asynchronous patterns is not exactly wrong but NOT best practice in V3. So the suggested questions are not relevant.

Comment: The caution has to do with what the callback should return (`true` if `sendResponse` will be called async, `false` otherwise). There is no alternative to `sendResponse` in V3. Just look at the profile of @wOxxOm who marked your question as a duplicate, he knows what he's talking about. Like I've said many times before, when it comes to listeners' callbacks, there are no changes, like many other APIs, listeners use callback functions not promises. I'm pretty up to date with the Chrome Extension manifest V3 API and I'm telling you, these are the best practices.