# Encountering Challenges with Message Passing Between Content Script and Background Script in Chrome Extension (Manifest V3)

Tags: google-chrome-extension, manifest, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm facing an issue while attempting to send the message "login" from `login.js` to `background.js`. I intend for `background.js` to call a function named **initiateLogin** upon receiving this message, which, in turn, launches the authentication web flow. Subsequently, the **handleFlowResult** function should handle the exchange of the authCode for an access token.

Currently, the code implementation involves `login.js` sending the message to `background.js`, and initiateLogin being called correctly. However, when the **initiateLogin** function sends the message "needCodes" to `login.js` to retrieve codes, the message is successfully passed to `login.js`. Still, the `background.js` does not wait for the response from `login.js` and promptly sends back an empty response.

I have checked the documentation regarding the use of `return true;` and tried incorporating the async keyword at various points, but the issue persists. I am using a function **sendMessageAsync** which sends the message, but the issue was still there when I replacced it with `chrome.runtime.sendMessage()` statement. The provided code snippet represents a simplified version of my implementation.

I'm seeking help in identifying what might be causing this issue.

This is my `background.js`

```
js

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(handleMessage);

async function handleMessage(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log("handleMessage - request:", request);
    console.log("handleMessage - sender:", sender);

    if (request.message === "login") {
        console.log("handleMessage - Initiating login process");
        await initiateLogin();
        sendResponse({ response: "loggedIn" });
        return true;
    } else if (request.message === "logout") {
        console.log("handleMessage - Logging out user");
        emptyTokenData();
        sendResponse({ response: "logout successfully" });
        return true;
    }
}

// Login and authentication functions
async function initiateLogin() {
    console.log("initiateLogin - Initiating login process");
    try {
        const { x, y, z } = await sendMessageAsync({
            message: "needCodes",
        });
        await handleFlowResult(result, x, a, b);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error during login initiation:", error);
    }
}

async function handleFlowResult(result, x, a, b) {
    const codeData = { result, x, a, b };
    try {
        const data = await sendMessageAsync({
            message: "exCode",
            messageData: codeData,
        });
        console.log(
            "handleFlowResult - Token exchange successful. Data:",
            data,
        );
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error during handleFlowResult:", error);
    }
}

async function sendMessageAsync(message) {
    console.log(
        "sendMessageAsync - initiating sending message to login.js:",
        message,
    );

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage(message, (response) => {
            if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
                reject(new Error(chrome.runtime.lastError));
            } else {
                console.log(
                    "sendMessageAsync - Response from login.js:",
                    response,
                );
                resolve(response);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

This is `login.js`

```
js

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    const loginButton = document.getElementById("login-button");
    if (loginButton) {
        loginButton.addEventListener("click", loginUser);
    }
});
async function loginUser() {
    // Send login message to background.js
    const response = await chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
        message: "login",
    });
    console.log("response from outside if block: ", response);

    if (response && response.response === "loggedIn") {
        console.log("response from inside if block: ", response);
    } else {
        console.error("Login failed:", response);
    }
}

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(async (request, sender, sendResponse) => {
    let data;
    switch (request.message) {
        case "needCodes":
            data = await handleNeedCodes();
            break;

        default:
            console.error("Unknown message type:", request.message);
            sendResponse({ error: "Unknown message type" });
            break;
    }
    //Ensure you handle the response asynchronously
    if (sendResponse) {
        sendResponse({ data });
    }
    return true;
});

// Function to handle the "needCodes" message
async function handleNeedCodes() {
    try {
        const foo = await abc(x); // Ensure that abc is defined or imported
        console.log(foo);
        return foo;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error during handleNeedCodes:", error);
        throw error; // Propagate the error to the caller
    }
}
```

Comment: used this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44056271/chrome-runtime-onmessage-response-with-async-await?rq=2

Comment: You've used it incorrectly: onMessage listener cannot be declared as async. You need to use two functions.